# Why is getcwd() not ISO C++ compliant?

Tags: c++, iso

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235450.aspx) states that getcwd() has been deprecated and that the ISO C++ compatible _getcwd should be used instead, which raises the question: what makes getcwd() not ISO-compliant?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Functions not specified in the standard are supposed to be prefixed by an underscore as an indication that they're vendor-specific extensions or adhere to a non-ISO standard.  Thus the "compliance" here was for Microsoft to add an underscore to the name of this specific function since it's not part of the ISO standard.

Comment: I don't think anyone ever claimed that the Win32 API was compliant with anything whatsoever. windows.h doesn't even compile if you disable language extensions in VC++. :)

Comment: The confusing thing is that they did this to posix functions that weren't in standard C headers too.

Comment: The Windows API is not part of the C or C++ runtime library.

Comment: @Stuart - That's not confusing... breaking POSIX seems to be their modus operandi.  It's beneficial to Microsoft to encourage developers to use Win32 APIs instead.

Answer (score 26):

There is a [good discussion](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.misc/msg/e668fa9f36e57c67) about that. [P.J. Plauger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PJ_Plauger) answers to this

> I'm the guy who insisted back in 1983 that the space of
>   names available to a C program be partitioned into:
>
> **a)** those defined by the implementation for the benefit of the programmer (such as printf)
>    **b)** those reserved to the programmer (such as foo) 
>    **c)** those reserved to the implementation (such as _unlink)
>
> We knew even then that "the implementation" was too monolithic --
>   often more than one source supplies bits of the implementation --
>   but that was the best we could do at the time. Standard C++
>   has introduced namespaces to help, but they have achieved only
>   a fraction of their stated goals. (That's what happens when you
>   standardize a paper tiger.)
>
> In this particular case, Posix supplies a list of category (a) names
>   (such as unlink) that you should get defined when and only when you
>   include certain headers. Since the C Standard stole its headers from
>   Unix, which is the same source as for Posix, some of those headers
>   overlap historically. Nevertheless, compiler warnings should have
>   some way of taking into account whether the supported environment
>   is "pure" Standard C++ (a Platonic ideal) or a mixed C/C++/Posix
>   environment. The current attempt by Microsoft to help us poor
>   programmers fails to take that into account. It insists on treating
>   unlink as a category (b) name, which is myopic.

Well, GCC will not declare POSIX names in strict C mode, at least (though, it still does in C++ mode):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    &fdopen;
    return 0;
}
```

Output using `-std=c99`

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:4: error: 'fdopen' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

You will have to tell it explicitly that you are operating in a mixed C/Posix by using feature test macros or not passing any specific standard. It will then default to `gnu89` which assumes a mixed environment (`man feature_test_macros`). Apparently, MSVC does not have that possibility.

Comment: GCC does not declare POSIX or even standard C names. That is the job of glibc.

Answer (score 5):

For the record, `getcwd()` wasn't deprecated by ISO.  It was "deprecated" by Microsoft.  Microsoft rewrote many C functions -- often with a little better security in mind (say, string functions that also take a `max_length` parameter).  They then had their compiler spit out these warnings, which I consider bogus because no standards group deprecated any of the functions declared deprecated.

Comment: _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS and forget :)

Comment: Question:  "why is getcwd() not ISO compliant?/This MSDN article states that getcwd() has been deprecated ..."

Answer:  "getcwd() is not deprecated; Microsoft is spitting out warnings with a strange definition of 'deprecated'."

How does that not answer the question?  In what way was I asking for clarification?

Comment: `getcwd()` is deprecated by GNU too. See the man page "For portability and security reasons, use of getwd() is deprecated."

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist: According to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html (and your comment), GNU calls`getwd()` deprecated, but also says also says "Use `getcwd()` instead." (in section "CONFORMING TO").  Plus, so far, Open Group has not deprecated `getcwd()` ( http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html ).

Answer (score 4):

As others have already pointed out, getcwd is not included in ISO C++, but is part of [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getcwd.html)/IEEE Std 1003.1.

Microsoft has decided to include some of the most commonly used POSIX functions in their C standard library (but prefix these functions with an underscore to essentially discourage their usage).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware getcwd() has never been part of ISO Standard C++. _getcwd() definitely isn't, as standard names will not begin with an underscore.

In fact, the MSDN article links to a man page that says it is declared in **direct.h**, which is not a Standard C++ header file. The article seems bogus to me.

Answer (score 3):

To add on to Dan Olson's post: See [ANSI C Compliance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45aft37a.aspx) page on MSDN

> The names of Microsoft-specific functions and global variables begin with a single underscore. These names can be overridden only locally, within the scope of your code. For example, when you include Microsoft run-time header files, you can still locally override the Microsoft-specific function named _open by declaring a local variable of the same name. However, you cannot use this name for your own global function or global variable.

Answer (score 3):

The MSDN article is somewhat confusing in what a normal person would conclude from just a quick reading (if they don't read it with a very careful lawyer eye).

What the MSDN article says is: getcwd() is not compliant with the ISO C++ standard.  To comply with that ISO C++ standard for naming of functions (which is what getcwd violates), Microsoft properly put an _ on the front of the function, so the same function becomes _getcwd().  That is the ISO C++ compliant way of naming the function because getcwd() and _getcwd() are not an ISO C++ standard function, but are a Microsoft (vendor) specific, or implementation specific function.

The article does not indicate what a C++ ISO standard call to get the working directory would be... though thats what folks tend to read at a quick glance.