# Alternative function in iostream.h for getch() of conio.h?

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm trying to hold the screen on my output using the header file `<iostream.h>`, but I don't know any equivalent function to the `getch()` & `clrscr()` functions of `<conio.h>` in `<iostream.h>` or any other C++ library.  Are there any such functions?

Comment: In C++, the header is simply `#include <iostream>`, **not** `#include <iostream.h>`

Comment: `<iostream>` may be the standard but `clrscr()` isn't standard, so it actually makes sense to find that in a non-standard header.

Comment: I have actually always wondered and meant to ask why some people always start a program with clrscr() and end with getch() in the first place.

Comment: Related post - [getch is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/814975/465053)

Answer (score -24, accepted):

if you work on windows you can use system("pause"), this will give you "press any key to continue" message.

Comment: This works, but it's a [bad habit to get into](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/).

Comment: Shouldn't even use this at all.

Comment: There is also a `std::cin.ignore();` for this.

Answer (score 30):

The `conio.h` functions are compiler extensions to the language, not part of C or C++. There isn't a direct replacement in standard C++.

For getch(), `int ch = std::cin.get();` is probably the closest equivalent -- but bear in mind that this will read from buffered standard input, whereas I think the conio.h `getch` does an unbuffered read.

Any implementation of `clrscr()` is going to be very platform-dependent -- not all screens or terminals have a notion of clearing, and those that do have wildly differing ways to access that functionality.

If you need to treat the terminal as something other than a set of character streams, your best bet is probably to look for a library which hides the details of the underlying terminal, screen or console from you. If you're on a UNIXish system, look at the curses or ncurses library; I don't know of any suggestions for other OSes.

Answer (score 9):

getch() and clrscr() will work with C++. Include conio.h

However, if you CANNOT (for some reason) include conio.h,

how about cin>>dummy_var with a display message asking the user to press enter?

Comment: +1 because most interesting things you can do with C and C++ are actually not in the standard. Neither standard is intended to be complete, and the fact that you can include headers other than the standard-mandated ones is very much by design.

Answer (score 8):

just use cin.get();

Answer (score 3):

Just use these two functions:

```
fflush(stdin);
getchar();
```

Visual studio and Dev C++ include this in its `iostream` header so no need to include extra header file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/257203/183120
`fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour called out in the C standard 7.18.5.2/2.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I usually use:

```
#include<iostream>
...
std::getchar();
```

Answer (score 2):

*Late answer*, you can use `std::cin.get()`, this should work with most compilers. If that doesn't work, try adding another.

```
int main () {

    // ...

    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0x00;
}
```

Using `system("PAUSE")` is only available on Windows and is a [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong) programming [habit](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html). The reason for this is it literally **pauses** or **freezes** your program as opposed to just waiting for an input. ie. a keypress to exit.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this is an old question but I am going to answer nonetheless because people may be looking for an answer to a similar question.

`conio.h` is an (ancient) Windows and MS-DOS/PC-DOS C library that was, and still is used for very basic, bare-metal keyboard input and handling in a Windows/DOS environment.

Both `getch()` and `clrscr()` are non-standard additions by this header, and should be avoided when possible for the standard C functions. `getch()` can usually be replaced with `scanf()`, `fread()`, in C and `std::cin`  and `std::cin.get` in C++. As for `clrscr()`, the closest you can get is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    printf("\n");
}
```

**OR:**

There is also `ncurses.h` on *nix environments. [Here's a link](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) to some info about that.

Answer (score 1):

The platform-specific function `getch()` from conio.h has two special features:

- ***No echoing*** of characters.
- ***Unbuffered*** reading of characters.

The echoing is done by the terminal outside of the C/C++ environment. It can only be controlled by manipulating the terminal. Also, it is nearly impossible to get unbuffered I/O with the iostream.h header.

**Therefore it is not possible to get anywhere near `getch()` using iostream.h alone.**

(There are plenty of `getch()`implementations around, e.g. using termios.h to disable echoing.)

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the information I was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

For `clrscr()`  I generally use

```
system("cls");       //Windows
system("clear");     // Linux
```

And for the `getch()` function I agree with  `@iKlsR` , just use cin.get() 2 times.

```
{   ...
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

and if you are looking to pause the system for a moment or specific time interval use:

```
system("sleep 5s"); //for linux
```

basically the function `system("x")` runs the command `x` in terminal. So you can just exploit it by using the different function in place of `x`. (be specific to use the commands which are related to your distro or OS)

Answer (score -6):

You can use system("pause"), which produces the "press any key to continue" message. But it works in the windows environment only. I think all the "system" commands are dos commands. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You're halfway right. `system(<cmd>)` executes `<cmd>` using the command processor of whatever OS you're currently on. [Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/0). It's also generally considered bad form because it's not portable between platforms.