# Is there a standard getch() equivalent in C++?

Tags: c++

I know that getch is not a standard C/C++ function but I tend to like it because it doesn't need you to press enter before returning. So I'd like to know if there is any equivalent in standard C++ that has the same effect (doesn't require you to press enter)?

I have read similar questions on this site but none of their answers say whether there is a standard and portable equivalent or not.

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: If there were a function like that, you would've probably seen it used in some of the answers you say you read.

Comment: I believe it's quite hard to have it in standard, since standard doesn't say when console will give data to your program.

Comment: Why not just use a combination of fopen(stdin) and fgetc() ?

Comment: `fgetc(stdin)` does exactly the same thing as `getchar()`, which in most implementations is line-buffered (that is, waits for the user to hit "enter").

Comment: Use cin.get();
<br>
As suggested <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/4456902/3645550"> Here </a>

Answer (score 6):

There is a portable-ish equivalent if you use one of the "curses" libraries, such as [*ncurses*](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [ncurses](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/docs/HOWTO/other-formats/html_single/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO.html). It's the best and simplest alternative out there.

**Sample Code:**

```
#include <ncurses.h>

 int main()
 {  
   initscr();                   /* Start curses mode          */
   printw("Hello World !!!");   /* Print Hello World          */
   refresh();                   /* Print it on to the real screen */
   getch();                     /* Wait for user input */
   endwin();                    /* End curses mode        */

   return 0;
 }
```