# Linux equivalent for conio.h getch()

Tags: c++, linux, getch

Previously I use c++/c compilers on windows which support the `#include <conio.h>` header file but on Linux where I have

```
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software...
```

I want a function which works exactly as `getch()`. I don't know why my compiler doesn't support the header file `#include <conio.h>`

After searching on net I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377403/alternative-function-in-iostream-h-for-getch-of-conio-h) which says that `cin.get();` is probably the closest equivalent but these two are different in the way that if we write `getch()` it does not display the character entered on the console whereas if we enter a character using `cin.get()` it displays the character on the console. I don't want the character to be displayed on the console.

using `getchar()` also displays the character on the console.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276546/how-to-implement-getch-function-of-c-in-linux

Comment: This is what happens when you are taught ancient, platform-specific APIs instead of standard C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit does this curses.h comes into standard c++ and conio.h doesn't?

Comment: Neither `conio` nor `curses` are standard C libraries. The first is for windows, the other for linux (although there might be vice-versa implementations).

Comment: Please choose one of C and C++.

Comment: @WeatherVane `curses` is an industrial standard library (part of SUS) and not “for Linux,” it's a highly portable software that runs on countless operating systems.

Comment: If you do not wish to use curses, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux

Comment: BTW, it's not a compiler issue. gcc would happily include `<conio.h>` if such a file existed.

Comment: @WeatherVane Curious, I was using `curses.h` in the 1980s, long before Linux was even thought of. Unix, yes, Linux-specific, no.

Comment: @EJP ok thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Equivalent to getch() & getche() in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of different ways of doing this more portably.  The simplest is to use [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)):

```
#include "curses.h"

int main() {
    initscr();
    addstr("hit a key:");
    getch();
    return endwin();
}
```

Comment: can you explain `initscr();` ?

Comment: @Lovely: it initializes the curses library and is needed before calling any other function.  `endwin()` then shuts things down and needs to be called before the program exits.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread answering this question with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>

char getch() {
    char buf = 0;
    struct termios old = { 0 };
    fflush(stdout);
    if (tcgetattr(0, &old) < 0) perror("tcsetattr()");
    old.c_lflag    &= ~ICANON;   // local modes = Non Canonical mode
    old.c_lflag    &= ~ECHO;     // local modes = Disable echo. 
    old.c_cc[VMIN]  = 1;         // control chars (MIN value) = 1
    old.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;         // control chars (TIME value) = 0 (No time)
    if (tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old) < 0) perror("tcsetattr ICANON");
    if (read(0, &buf, 1) < 0) perror("read()");
    old.c_lflag    |= ICANON;    // local modes = Canonical mode
    old.c_lflag    |= ECHO;      // local modes = Enable echo. 
    if (tcsetattr(0, TCSADRAIN, &old) < 0) perror ("tcsetattr ~ICANON");
    return buf;
 }
```

It uses ***termios*** driver interface library wich is part of POSIX (IEEE 1003.1)

For more references about this library read:  [The  header contains the definitions used by the terminal I/O interfaces](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/termios.h.html)

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I encountered this `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘read’; did you mean ‘fread’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   15 |     if (read(0, &buf, 1) < 0) perror("read()");
      |         ^~~~
      |         fread
`

Comment: `read` is a syscall with prototype provided when you `#include <unistd.h>`. Though I would recommend a method that doesn't need to change the keyboard mode for every character added. Better to put the keyboard into "raw" (non-canonical) mode once, take all input needed in raw mode and then return to "cooked" (canonical) mode.