# Why does my arithmetic mean function always return 0?

Tags: c, average

In the code below, the function `calculo()` doesn't return any values.  It was supposed to return the arithmetic mean between `cont` and `aluno` variables, but it always returns 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int i;

int calculo(int alunos, int *p) {
    int cont = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < alunos; i++)
        cont += p[i];
    return cont / alunos;
}

int main()
{
    int *p, alunos, media;

    printf("Digite a quantidade de alunos na turma \n");
    scanf("%d", &alunos);

    p = (int*)calloc(alunos, sizeof(int));

    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("Memória Insuficiente");
        return 1;
    }
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 1; i < alunos + 1; i++) {
        *p = rand() % 10;
        printf("Nota do Aluno [%d]: \t %d \n", i, *p);
    }

    media = calculo(alunos, p);
    printf("A Media Aritimetica da turma e:\t %d", media);
    getche();
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What did you observe when inspecting the values using your debugger? You are aware how integer value division works?

Comment: Why is this question tagged as "C++", when it doesn't actually have a single line of C++ code, only a bunch of old, crufty, C?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Found some C++ in line 4 ;)

Comment: Take a look at how you're reading in your numbers, and where you store them

Comment: The problem is only reading data into one element of `p`.     Also be aware that your function does integer division for `cont/alunos`, which ALWAYS rounds toward zero.   So the average of `1` and `2` (calculated as `(1 + 2)/2` in your function will give a result of  `1`, not `1.5`.

Comment: @LeonardoJob Welcome to StackOverflow.  As pointed out, your program is completely in C style and not C++...so the `#include <iostream>` is not used.  It's very important on this site to distinguish in your questions whether you intend to use C style *(e.g. `printf("...")` and `malloc(...)` and `strcpy(...)`)* or C++ style *(e.g. `std::cout << "..."` and `new ...` and `std::string`)*, because it deeply affects the answers you will get.  You should also know that conio.h is very old, [and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34474627/)--should be avoided in questions here.

Comment: @HostileFork Thanks for all the help, there are so many things wrong that I didnt even know, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @LeonardoJob Sure thing.  Be persistent, StackOverflow can sometimes be hard for new users...but it's just about the best way to get better that there is.  If you want to learn a language, it can be very useful to monitor a tag and see the other questions go by.  You learn fast--not just about the language, but about what makes questions get treated well vs. downvoted and complained about.  Like I said, it helps to make a strong decision if you want to be pursuing [tag:c] or [tag:c++], maybe following those tags for a while would help you decide which is more your style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> srand(time(NULL));
> for (i = 1; i < alunos + 1; i++) {
>     *p = rand() % 10;  // <<=========================== here
>     printf("Nota do Aluno [%d]: \t %d \n", i, *p);
> }
> ```

you are assigning to `*p` aka `p[0]` over and over again. What you perhaps want to do is

```
srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i < alunos; ++i) {
    p[i] = rand() % 10;
    printf("Nota do Aluno [%d]: \t %d \n", i + 1, p[i]);
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much!, But i dont think i get it.  If p[i] stores the number inside the array, so what would *p store then?.

Comment: In C and C++ `something[index]` is just syntactic sugar for `*(something + index)` ... so `*p` which is the same as `*(p+0)` could be read as `p[0]`.