# Alternative for getch() c++

Tags: c++

Can someone give me a good alternative for getch() function in c++ ? I want to read signs from keyboard and getch makes error on ideone and on online judge in codeblocks all goes well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative function in iostream.h for getch() of conio.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377403/alternative-function-in-iostream-h-for-getch-of-conio-h)

Comment: Write your own `getch()`. Here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux

Answer (score 2):

try below

int ch = std::cin.get();

Comment: `std::cin.get()` performs a buffered input while `getch()` peformes unbuffered input.  On my system that practically means that I need to press `Enter` twice with `std::cin.get()`