# Masking the user input as asterisks in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, console-application, windows-console

I need to create a simple password program where the program asks user to input password and when user inputs, it shows the characters as asterisks.

Every tutorial out there uses `getch()` (in `conio.h`). But I don't want to use it. Is there any easy alternative for doing so?

I'm using Windows 10.

P.S: Please don't confuse this to be a duplicate of this question: [Alternative function in iostream.h for getch() of conio.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377403/alternative-function-in-iostream-h-for-getch-of-conio-h)

Because that question asks for holding screen output whereas I need to mask the input as asterisks.

Comment: @seccpur um, this is not relevant to my question.

Comment: You can't do this with C++ standard library, you need platform specific APIs. So, which OS?

Comment: I'm using windows 10

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413445/reading-a-password-from-stdcin shows how to just silence echoing what user types. But you want to show astrixes, which makes this more complicated.

Comment: @hyde yes, thanks for that link. It's useful to know how to silence the echo types but I still need to show asterisks :(

Comment: So you need to figure out  how to read unbuffered keyboard input in terminal. I think on windows you need to listen to keyboard events, then get the character from event and print asterisk.

Comment: Well, I have no idea how to read to keyboard events except for getch. and I've been searching but it only shows getch (and curses which is in linux) so I guess there's no other way?

Comment: @seccpur Huh???

Answer (score 2):

We are here in non standard functionality.  So, whatever you'll do, it will not be portable.

The native console way would be to [`ReadConsoleInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events). In your case, you would first disable the echo and the line input mode by clearing the console mode flags `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT` and `ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT`.  Then you would react on key events by displaying '*'.  Don't forget to restore the inital console mode at the end.

A shortcut would be to just save and change the console mode (as shown in the code above), an then looping for `cin.get()` and echoing `cout<<'*';` followed by `cout.flush();` to be sure that the output doesn't wait in a buffer, creating discomfort for the user.

Comment: Alternatively, programs such as "runas.exe" call [`CredUICmdLinePromptForCredentialsW`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincred/nf-wincred-creduicmdlinepromptforcredentialsw). It opens "CONIN$" and "CONOUT$" directly instead of using the standard handles. The flag `CREDUI_FLAGS_EXCLUDE_CERTIFICATES` is required, and you probably also want `CREDUI_FLAGS_DO_NOT_PERSIST`. If you have the user name already, you can pass it as `pszTargetName` (in addition to `UserName`) instead of passing a server name, in combination with the flag `CREDUI_FLAGS_USERNAME_TARGET_CREDENTIALS`.

Comment: However, `CredUICmdLinePromptForCredentialsW` does not show asterisks for typed input.