# Creating folders in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, filesystems

I have recently started working in C++ and came across this situation when I have to create a directory while executing my code. The code is working fine when I have to create a single folder but it fails when I have to create another folder withing this newly created folder.

Suppose, I am in `C:` and want to store my file in `C:/A/B/` .The following piece of code using `mkdir()` works fine if I have to store my file in `C:/A/` but fails when I am adding another folder `B`.

Following is my code snippet:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string stringpath = "C:/A/B/"; 
    int status = mkdir(stringpath.c_str(),0777);

    if(status!=0)
    {
        //.....
    }
    else
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

Can someone help me in creating this directory where I can have any number of folders inside the parent directory? (P.S:I have added the header files sys/stat.h,iostream and string)

Comment: standard C++11 does not know about folders (the correct name is directory; folders are just a GUI artefact) so your question is operating system specific

Comment: ``mkdir`` is not part of C++11. It's OS specific API

Comment: See [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and read [n3337](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n3337.pdf) to learn more about C++11. You'll see that "folders" or "directories" are not mentioned there. [mkdir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html) is in POSIX. Windows has [_mkdir](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw.aspx) & [CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa363855(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: In C++17, you have [create_directories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory), before, you have boost's version.

Answer (score 18):

This is how you do it in C++17:

```
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
fs::create_directories("./a/b/c")
```

Answer (score 5):

`mkdir()` creates only the last component of the specified path. In your example, it will create only `B`. If any of the parent directories do not exist (ie, if `A` does not exist), the function fails with `ENOENT`.  You need to split up the path and call `mkdir()` for every intermediate directory in the path, ignoring `EEXIST` errors as you go.

```
status = mkdir("C:/A/", 0777);
if ((status < 0) && (errno != EEXIST)) ...

status = mkdir("C:/A/B/", 0777);
if ((status < 0) && (errno != EEXIST)) ...
```

If you don't want to handle this manually, use a wrapper that handles it for you, such as Boost's [`create_directories()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#create_directories) function:

> `bool create_directories(const path& p);`
>   `bool create_directories(const path& p, system::error_code& ec);`
>
> Effects: Establishes the postcondition by calling `create_directory()` for any element of `p` that does not exist.
>
> Postcondition: `is_directory(p)`
>
> Returns: true if a new directory was created, otherwise false.
>
> Throws: As specified in Error reporting.
>
> Complexity: `O(n+1)`where `n` is the number of elements of `p` that do not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the following:

```
string stringpath = "C:/A/B/";
int status = mkdir(stringpath.c_str(),0777);
```

**If** 
C:/A/ directory exists. If its not exists, then do the following:

```
string stringpath = "C:/A/";
int status = mkdir(stringpath.c_str(),0777);
stringpath = "C:/A/B/";
int status = mkdir(stringpath.c_str(),0777);
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 you can use the experimental functios:

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>
...
std::stringstream bufH;
bufH << dirName << fName;
if (!std::experimental::filesystem::exists(bufH.str()))
{
 std::experimental::filesystem::create_directories(bufH.str());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the octal flag 7777 like this to have all the rights necessary to create this folder.

```cpp
int status = mkdir(stringpath.c_str(), 7777);
```

Or do a chmod in the A folder like that :
chmod -r 7777 *