# C++ how to create folder

Tags: c++, filesystems

MY CURRENT CODE

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<direct.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<filesystem>

int main(){
    int choice;
    std::string folder_n;

    std::cin >> choice;

    if(choice == 2){
        std::cout << "Enter folder name" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> folder_n;

        filesystem::create_directory(folder_n);
        std::cout << "created folder named " << folder_n << std::endl ;
            
    }

    return 0;
}
```

MY PROBLEM -->
error: 'filesystem' has not been declared
can anybody tell why is this error coming and how to fix it

````
Note : 1. filesystem is included in my c++ version because intellisense is showing filesystem
       2. I am using MinGw 
       3. My MinGW version is 9.2.0```
````

Comment: Missing `#include <string>`, `#include <iostream>`.  Unnecessary `#include <windows.>`, `#include <fstream>`, `#include <direct.h>`, `#include <conio.h>`, `#include <sys/stat.h>`.  And finally missing `std::` on `filesystem::create_directory`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960492/creating-folders-in-c

Comment: Try `std::filesystem::create_directory`, or `std::experimental::filesystem::create_directory` if you have an old standard lib.

Comment: done that now this error ---> name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name

Comment: Make sure that your version of mingw is using c++17. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734397/which-c-standard-is-the-default-when-compiling-with-g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734397/which-c-standard-is-the-default-when-compiling-with-g)

Answer (score 0):

Create_directory works only with c++ 17.

In compiling, try g++ -std=c++17 file.cpp.

This is the site for all the file system function [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)