# How to create a folder that has a sharing access to "everyone" using c++

Tags: c++, directory, permissions

I need help on how to add "everyone" to the folder's share option property using c++.

this is my code on how to create new folder

```
#include <direct.h>
    int main()
    {
          mkdir("c:/scan");
          return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This is for Windows 10 I assume?

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes its for windows 10

Comment: I still don't get windows 10. 20 years ago they were on Windows 98 and then suddenly a massive step backward.

Comment: Is [_chmod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/chmod-wchmod?view=vs-2019) what you're looking for, or not exactly?

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402499/mkdir-c-function

Comment: @Chipster i think _chmod is only for linux, need solution for windows

Comment: @DwiNovitasari But the link I posted is on Microsoft's site. That usually means it should be available on Windows too. But I could be wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, following should create a directory, and set permissions to give all users access:

```
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
fs::create_directory(path);
fs::permissions(path, fs::perms::all);
```

Comment: i tried to run this #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main()
{
    
 fs::create_directory("C:/newscan");
 fs::permissions(path, fs::perms::all);  
} 
and got this following error 4 35 D:\kerja\Untitled2.cpp [Error] experimental/filesystem: No such file or directory

Comment: @DwiNovitasari make sure you have the compiler set to compile to the c++ 17 Standard revision. Exactly how you do this with your development tools should be documented by those development tools.

Comment: @DwiNovitasari Also note that the path needs to be the same for both calls. `fs::path dir = "C:/newscan"; fs::create_directory(dir); fs::permissions(dir, fs::perms::all);`

Comment: @TedLyngmo hello it gives me new error instead c:\mingw\mingw\include\c++\8.2.0\bits\fs_path.h|237|error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' and 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path')|