# Emulating mkdir -p with the C++ standard library

Tags: c++, path, mkdir, std-filesystem

This question: [mkdir c++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10402499/1593077) tells us how to create a directory programmatically in C++, introducing us to `std::filesystem::create` - which acts similarly to the `mkdir` command in Unix shells.

However, this does not seem to allow for recursively creating the entire path: `mkdir -p /path/to/nonexisting/dir/and/then/some`. Is there some facility in the filesystem library for doing that? Or - should we just loop over the path elements, checking for existence and writability as necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `std::filesystem::create_directories()` for which you can find more detailed information in the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory).

Comment: That's a confusing name... :-(

Comment: @einpoklum Agreed, but I always read the details below just to be sure of what the function exactly/really does, whatever the name :)