# Reading a text file to a simple structure in C

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, codeblocks

I have the following structure:

```
  struct dados{
    int triage;
    int doctors;
    int shift;
    int mq_max;
}data;
```

and am trying to read in the file config.txt which is composed of:

> TRIAGE=5DOCTORS=10SHIFT_LENGTH=5MQ_MAX=20

In the following manner:

```
int main{
    FILE *fp = fopen("config.txt","r");
    fscanf(fp,"TRIAGE=%dDOCTORS=%dSHIFT_LENGTH=%dMQ_MAX=%d",&data.triage,&data.doctors,&data.shift,&data.mq_max);
 return 0;
}
```

but all it does is print memory addresses, and obviously I need the values next to the `=`.

Comment: you dont need the mallocs

Comment: and this code doesnt print anything. please show running code

Comment: and check the return value of fscanf and fopen

Comment: @pm100 fopen returns 0 and scanf returns -1

Comment: fopen retruning 0 says it failed to open the file, do perror after the failure

Comment: @pm100 but why is it failing to open? I have the txt file in the same folder where main.c is

Comment: The folder where your program is may not be the current working directory. [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746510/unable-to-open-a-file-with-fopen).

Comment: Nevermind it was just a prank broooo.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you a time waster?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP wrote in comments that it was "a prank". There is someone who knows C quite well and keeps making a new account and asking tricky questions which are not real, for some motive known only to that person.