# ISO C++ and the infamous underscore

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, msdn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is getcwd() not ISO C++ compliant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647704/why-is-getcwd-not-iso-c-compliant)

After searching for availability of `execvp` on Windows, particularly with VisualStudio, I've ended up with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235414.aspx ...

However, it says I should use `_execvp` instead of `execvp`. GCC also seems to support `_execvp`. But what's the deal with the underscore? why is using `_execvp` more ISO C++ conformant than using `execvp`?

Also, wouldn't the term *deprecated* imply that `execvp` would be removed with some undefined VisualStudio version?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647704/why-is-getcwd-not-iso-c-compliant. Basically, names that begin with an underscore in the global namespace [are reserved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for implementations, so they should use that.

Comment: And yes, that means it can go away at any release.

Comment: @GMan: noted... it's a little odd though. :-)

Comment: If you want to use a POSIX name, just include a POSIX header. `<unistd.h>` is not part of the C standard library, so once you include it, you're writing a standard POSIX program, not a standard C program. Likewise, this isn't something that GCC does or doesn't support, it's an operating system issue. Mac OS X uses GCC but does not define `_execvp`.